# Excessive data usage on Laptop over Mobile when Streaming Videos

Tags: networking, browser, internet

On my limited data, I can attend roughly 5-6 online classes on my phone(not live, pre-recorded). On the other hand, when I take the same classes on my laptop, I can barely get through one class. I couldn't change the video quality because they don't use YouTube. They have their own video player, but there is no way to change the quality of the video.

What can I do to cut down on my data usage?

Comment: What OS are you using? How is the laptop connected to the Internet?

Comment: On Ubuntu and Windows 7. I use Mobile hotspot

Comment: If there is no quality settings in the player, you can do nothing about it on your computer. You need some proxy which download full quality video stream, re-encode it and send it to you. It's not a trivial thing... Or maybe you can try to ask the lector to adjust his stream settings to save bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestion, @lluser.

I used Google Colab to download the video from the source, re-encode it, and then download it in lower quality.